# Problems with a proof of the Minkowski Inequality for real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have some problems with the following proof I found of the Minkowski's Inequality for real sequences.

*To make clear what I am OK with, and with what I have problems, I decomposed the proof in various parts, with my numbered questions & comments behind every parts.*

---

> **Minkowski's Inequality:**
> For any $(x_m), (y_m) \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$ and $1 \leq p < \infty$
> $$ \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty | x_i + y_i |^p \bigg)^\frac{1}{p} \leq \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty | x_i |^p \bigg)^\frac{1}{p} + \bigg( \sum_{i=1}^\infty | y_i |^p \bigg)^\frac{1}{p} \hspace{0.3cm}(1).$$

> *Proof*:
> Take any $(x_m),(y_m) \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$ and fix any $1 \leq p < \infty$. If either $\sum^{\infty} |x_i|^p = \infty$ or $\sum^{\infty} |y_i|^p = \infty$, then $(1)$ becomes trivial, so we assume that $\sum^{\infty} |x_i|^p < \infty$ and $\sum^{\infty} |y_i|^p < \infty$. $(1)$ is also trivially true if either $(x_m)$ or $(y_m)$ equals $(0,0,...)$, so we focus on the case where both $\alpha := \big( \sum^{\infty} |x_i|^p \big)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and $\beta := \big( \sum^{\infty} |y_i|^p \big)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ are positive real numbers.

Fair enough: everything makes sense.

> ￼Define the real sequences $( \hat{x}_m )$ or $( \hat{y}_m )$ by $\hat{x}_m := \frac{1}{\alpha} | x_m |$ and $\hat{y}_m := \frac{1}{\beta} | y_m |$. (Notice that $\sum^{\infty} |x_i|^p = 1 = \sum^{\infty} |y_i|^p$).

**1.** I really don't see why $\sum^{\infty} |x_i|^p = 1 = \sum^{\infty} |y_i|^p$.

> Using the triangle inequality for the absolute value function, and the fact that $t \mapsto t^p$ is an increasing map on $\mathbb{R}_+$, we find
> $$|x_i + y_i|^p \leq(|x_i|+|y_i|)^p = (\alpha|\hat{x}_i|+ \beta|\hat{y}_i|)^p = (\alpha+ \beta)^p \bigg( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{x}_i| + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{y}_i| \bigg)^p $$
> for each $i = 1,2,\dots$.

**2.** How does the fact that an arbitrary function $t$, when mapped to $t^p$ is increasing enter the picture (i.e. those inequalities)?
I find this point a bit cryptic.

> But since $t \mapsto t^p$ is a convex map on $\mathbb{R}_+$, we have
> $$ \bigg( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{x}_i| + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{y}_i| \bigg)^p \leq \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{x}_i|^p + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{y}_i|^p , \hspace{0.3cm}i= 1,2, \dots$$
> and hence
> $$|x_i + y_i|^p \leq (\alpha+ \beta)^p \bigg( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{x}_i|^p + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} |\hat{y}_i|^p \bigg). $$
> Summing over $i$, then,
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{i=1}^\infty | x_i + y_i |^p & \leq (\alpha+ \beta)^p \bigg( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} \sum_{i=1}^\infty |\hat{x}_i|^p + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} \sum_{i=1}^\infty |\hat{y}_i|^p \bigg)\\
> & = (\alpha+ \beta)^p \bigg( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} + \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} \bigg)^\frac{1}{p}.
> \end{align}
> Thus $\sum^\infty | x_i + y_i |^p \leq (\alpha + \beta)^p$ which is equivalent to $(1)$. $\square$

This part is ok.

---

As always, I am looking forward to any feedback or help.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: see also here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Minkowski's_Inequality_for_Sums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You donot have $\sum^{\infty} |x_i|^p = 1 = \sum^{\infty} |y_i|^p$. indeed you have $\sum^{\infty} |\hat{x}_i|^p = 1 = \sum^{\infty} |\hat{y}_i|^p$.

2:$$f(t)=t^p\Rightarrow f'(t)=pt^{p-1}￼\geq 0 ~~~\forall t\geq 0$$
so $f$ is an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}_+$

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the answer. Indeed, shame on me, I see that (1) is a typo. Still, I do not really get **(2)**. I mean, I see what you wrote, but what I don't see is why the fact that $t \mapsto t^p$ is increasing is *relevant* in the proof. *Could you please be more explicit about this point in the answer?*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, but actually it does not answer my problem: where does the fact that the function $t \mapsto t^p$ is increasing enters in the proof? I still cannot see it.

Comment: $|x_i + y_i|^p \leq(|x_i|+|y_i|)^p  $ is result of increasing function $t^p$ and   $|x_i + y_i| \leq |x_i|+|y_i| $

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment. Now it is clear.

Comment: you are welcome :)